# Not able to fire Button Click event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using a button and a grid inside the update panel, when user clicks on that button the result is updated in this grid

But this button is not raising any click event due to which code is not able to hit code behind.

following is the HTML code I am using

```
<div id="DivGridPendingCRSeeMore" class="editableDialogContentPanel" style="display: none">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="RecentGridPendingCRSeeMore" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="ButtonRecentGridPendingCRSeeMoreSearch" runat="server" Text="Search"
                    OnClick="ButtonRecentGridPendingCRSeeMoreSearch_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridPendingCRSeeMore" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AllowPaging="true"
                    PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PagerSettings-Visible="false" RowStyle-CssClass="gridDataRow"
                    CssClass="grid">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Request ID" DataTextField="Request_ID" SortExpression="Request_ID"
                            DataNavigateUrlFields="Request_ID" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ChangeRequestDetails.aspx?RequestID={0}"
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Territory ID" DataField="Territory_ID" SortExpression="Territory_ID"
                            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Submitted By" DataField="Submitted_By_Name" SortExpression="Submitted_By_Name"
                            ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Owner" DataField="owner_name" SortExpression="owner_name"
                            ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Type" DataField="Request_Type" SortExpression="Request_Type"
                            ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="CR_Status" SortExpression="CR_Status"
                            ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Submitted" DataField="Submit_Date" SortExpression="Submit_Date"
                            DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyy}" HtmlEncode="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Description (ID or Name)" DataField="Description" SortExpression="Description"
                            ItemStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <UC1:PagerControl ID="HomePendingCRPager" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
```

Following is the code behind handler

```
Protected Sub ButtonRecentGridPendingCRSeeMoreSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonRecentGridPendingCRSeeMoreSearch.Click


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `Trigger` in `UpdatePanel` like this

```
<Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ButtonRecentGridPendingCRSeeMoreSearch" EventName="Click"/> 
</Triggers>
```